# Excel xlXYScatter has lines when generated by C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm using an app written in WPF C# to generate an Excel Worksheet and plot out some data.
`xlXYScatterLines`, `xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers`, `xlXYScatterSmooth`, `xlXYScatterSmoothNomarkers` all worked out fine.

Except for `xlXYScatter` which always produces connects the data point with lines (= `xlXYScatterLines`), while it is supposed to display only scattered dots. Below is my code.

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)oSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(350,20,500,350);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter;
```

is this a bug?

**[SOLUTION - not answer]**

After two days of playing around, I accidentally found if I set the source data before defining chart type. The problem would not occur and xlXYScatter will show as xlXYScatter, not xlXYScatterLines.

```
chartPage.SetSourceData(Range, Missing.Value);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter;
```

I do not understand why and how this gets around the problem because it a intuitive to define the source after you define the chart, and in the opposite doesn't make much sense.
So I consider this as a solution, but not an answer. Hope someone can still answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set some specific value for ChartStyle - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k06h1bc5.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done this in C#, but in VBA I had some similar grief.  I ended up having to create the chart as `xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers`.  Then after the chart was created, I changed the type to `xlXYScatter`.  Ugly, but it seemed to work for me in VBA.

Comment: + 1, however that doesn't solve the problem in C#. I found a work around and edited with my question. May be you can deduce an explanation.

Comment: @KMC, I've been digging around in the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel libraries, but so far I haven't found the code that is causing this behavior(I guess I'd call it a bug).